# Using object parameters in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a app made in rails/angular where users can add movies to their watchlist. When a user adds a movie a activity record is created through the [Public Activity gem](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity)

This is my movie model (which is being tracked by the gem),

```
@movie = "Star Wars"

include PublicActivity::Model
tracked owner: -> (controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }
tracked :params => {
  :title => @movie
}
```

I found that by using this code in my movie model I can add a parameter to the activity record.

```
tracked :params => {
  :title => @movie,
}
```

Now when I add a new movie (and a new activity) it adds this to the activity record,

```
"parameters":{"title":"Star Wars"}
```

Ofcourse this is hardcoded and it should be the title of the movie object. Is is possible to get the data from the movie object in the movie model?

This is the movie table,

```
create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "release_date"
  t.string   "image"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.string   "movie_id"
  t.string   "backdrop"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    tracked :params => {
      :title => :get_title
    }
    def get_title
      title
    end
```

Unless I am understanding your question wrong. If so, correct me please :)

Comment: I don't think you misunderstood the question, I tried the code but I got an error `NoMethodError (undefined method `title' for #<Class:0x007ffbd3b13fb0>):
  app/models/movie.rb:8:in `<class:Movie>'
  app/models/movie.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:4:in `index'
`

Comment: Hi @alucardu, think we are in the good direction here then.I guess in this case self refers to the class, not object. I just removed it.  Can you also post the columns/attributes of your moxies table/model? I guessed the attribute to be 'title', so not surprised that it is not there.

Comment: Actually there is a column called `title` in the movie table. I've updated the question to show the movie table.

Comment: updated my answer. please try again and let me know how it goes.

Comment: also take a look here? https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity#assigning-custom-fields I am very familiar with the gem but it seems related to your needs.

Comment: Yea I've looked into custom fields, but I was unsure on how to apply them.  If I can create a link between the movie id and the activity record that would be better, but if it's just for adding data like the title etc, then using parameters looks good as well.